# Defining limits of an integral using the substitution $ x = (u-4)^2 + 1$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

I have the integral to calculate.

$$\int_{2}^{5} \frac{1}{4+\sqrt{x-1}} dx $$

using the substitution $ u = (u-4)^2 + 1$

so I did the following

$$x = (u-4)^2 + 1$$

and I  wanted to change the limits on the integral when evaulating the expression to

$$\int 2- \frac{8}{u}  \ du $$

so I did

$$ x-1 = (u - 4)^2 $$
$$ \sqrt{x-1} = u - 4 $$
$$ \sqrt{x-1} +4 = u $$

now I'm confused. When I substitute x = 5, 
I get $$±2 + 4 = u = 2 \ or \ 6$$

but why is the upper limit of the integral equal to 6 and not 2, using the positive root to get $$2 + 4 = u = 6$$

Comment: You want to find an interval $[a,b]$ so that as $u$ varies from $a$ to $b$, $x$ varies  from $2$ to $5$. You want the interval to be covered exactly once. You can check that a "mismatched" choice of values for $u$ will result in $x$ covering some part of $[2,5]$ more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to calculate the square root of $x$ then :$\sqrt{x^2}=\lvert x\rvert$, because the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is injective.

but if wanted to solve the equation $x^2=a$ so : $x= ±\sqrt{a}$ because the function $f(x)=x^2$ is not injective.

in your case, you have $x=5$ and $u=\sqrt{x-1} +4$, and you want to calculate $u .\ $ 
So: $\ u=2+4=6 \ $ i.e $\ (\sqrt{4}=\lvert 2\rvert=2) \ $

Answer (score 2):

The limits of integration indicate: $2\le x\le 5$.

You have the change: $u=4+\sqrt{x-1}.$

By plugging the numbers $2$ and $5$, you will get $5\le u \le 6.$

Here is another approach:

$$2\le x\le 5 \stackrel{-1}\Rightarrow $$
$$1\le x-1 \le 4 \stackrel{\sqrt{}}\Rightarrow$$
$$1\le \sqrt{x-1} \le 2 \stackrel{+4} \Rightarrow$$
$$5\le 4+\sqrt{x-1} \le 6.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt{x-1}=t$, which gives $1\leq t\leq2$.

Thus, $x-1=t^2$ and $dx=2tdt$.

Id est, $$\int\frac{1}{4+\sqrt{x-1}}dx=\int\frac{1}{t+4}2tdt=2\int\left(1-\frac{4}{t+4}\right)dt=$$
$$=2t-8\ln|(t+4)|+C=2\sqrt{x-1}-8\ln(4+\sqrt{x-1})+C.$$
Thus, $$\int\limits_2^5\frac{1}{4+\sqrt{x-1}}dx=4-8\ln6-2+8\ln5=2-8\ln1.2$$